# Why COLOR as an output semantic is not supported when targeting ps_4_0 but supported in vs_4_0?

Tags: directx-9

Take the following code as an example

```
struct vsout
{
  float4 pos : position;
  float4 clr : color;
};

cbuffer dmy : register(b0)
{
  float4x4 mat;
};

vsout vsmain(
  float4 pos : position,
  float2 tex : texcoord,
  float4 clr : color)
{
  vsout o;
  o.pos = mul(mat,pos);
  o.clr = clr;
  return o;
}

struct psout
{
  float4 clr : color;
};

psout psmain(
  float4 clr : color )
{
  psout o;
  o.clr = clr;
  return o;
}
```

`fxc /Evsmain /Tvs_4_0 demo.hlsl`,OK
`fxc /Epsmain /Tps_4_0 demo.hlsl`,FAILED
change psout to

```
struct psout
{
   float4 clr : sv_target;
};
```

`fxc /Epsmain /Tps_4_0 demo.hlsl`,OK
Per this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-semantics COLOR is a valid semantic for d3d9 and above. fxc I'm using is D3DCOMPILER_47.dll . How does this happen ? many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building without the `/Gec` flag so the HLSL compiler is not allowing 'backward compatibility' behavior.

"COLOR" in the Vertex Shader case is a vertex semantic which in most cases are 'user-defined' semantics.

"COLOR" is also a valid 'user-defined' semantic to bind the Vertex Shader output and the Pixel Shader input.

For strict compatibility you need to use `SV_Target` for the output of the pixel shader.

Ideally you'd also use `SV_Position` instead of `Position` for your Vertex Shader input, but you must match whatever you provided in the input layout. Whatever you use between the VS and PS must also be consistent.

> If you add `/Gec` to the pixel shader command-line then it will build because it supports the older Direct3D 9 style: `fxc /Epsmain /Gec /Tps_4_0 demo.hlsl`

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-semantics#vertex-shader-semantics)